# Can be find RichTextBox size based on Textvalue

Tags: c#, gridview

I need to find richtextbox actual size based on input value or text.
so how can i find actual size.

**code:**

```
RichTextBox rtf1=new RichTextBox ();

rtf1.text="Some text here"
```

please suggest me
Thanks.

Comment: Rtf is not length is much bigger than just the word's length becuase contains a lot of escape characters. So you can visit this for start http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.maxlength.aspx

Comment: I'm not sure but you probably can use GetPrefferedSize() method

Answer (score 0):

```
RichTextBox rtf1 = new RichTextBox();
            rtf1.TextLength.ToString();
```

Is this what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I'm misunderstanding, but the actual control size won't change based on the input value or text.

To obtain the size of the control use:

```
int height = rtf1.Height;
int width = rtf1.Width;
```

I apologise if I have misunderstood.

Answer (score 0):

After you create the control and set contents and any properties you want, you can use [Measure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.measure.aspx) to get the desired size:

```
rtf1.Measure(new Size(double.PositiveInfinity, double.PositiveInfinity));
```

After that you can use *rtf1.DesiredSize* property.